# Free up volume space in hard disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

I have 93.1GB for my windows partition or drive, however, I have no idea why there is so little usable space (1GB left), is there any software here that takes up so much space and can be removed harmlessly? I only use mathematica, microsoft offices, python, and in principle all others are redundant. Is it true that i have many software development libraries installed but can be removed?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could probably get away with uninstalling all of the visual studio related programs and the Windows SDK. Those are probably taking up a lot of space and you didn't mention doing any software development besides python. In addition, you could consider turning **NTFS compression** on to squeeze out a little extra space.

Comment: @BennettYeo I don't know how on earth i have so much development software installed.. and took up all my space.. i don't even know what they are for.. I have so much SQL sever software, i guess they are useless

Comment: @elpsyCongroo I have withdrawn my comment since you don't believe my statement.  I still stand by my statement though.

Comment: @Ramhound i think your statement is wrong based on my previous experience, e.g. Deleting compiler library, code won't run, deleting hardware driver, devices won't work. Whenever making a statement, please also offer compelling evidence to convince others to support your statement.

Comment: @music2myear  i think it was obvious enough :) for any people who used windows and read the title of the question

Comment: @elpsyCongroo - My statement wasn't wrong.  I indicated any software listed in that view of Add/Remove Programs can be removed, because any software listed in that view, was installed after Windows was installed.  Your device drivers, at least the ones listed in that view, are not required for Windows to boot

Comment: @elpsyCongroo No, it wasn't, and I'm an IT pro for 2 decades working mostly with Windows systems. The number of ways people describe issues is dizzying, and using precise language is necessary. I find it helpful to re-read thing I write trying to put myself in the shoes of someone who has no idea, no context, and then making sure that all the necessary information is there. In this case, your edit greatly clarified the issue and would have made it unnecessary for my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before uninstalling applications and libraries, I suggest running WinDirStat to graphically view which folders and files are using the most space on your HD.  You can download it using Ninite.

Comment: You can also download it from it's [official home](https://windirstat.net/download.html)...